# Are Intel Processors' GHz really matter?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, clockspeed, intel-core-i3, ghz

It has been confusing me for a long time. 
Say, an Intel 4th Gen dual-core i5-4200U which clocks at 1.6 GHz and up to 2.6 GHz and an Intel 4th Gen dual-core i3-4160 which clocks at 3.6 GHz.
As I see that they are both 4th Gen (Haswell), dual-core processors. Can I judge their processing speed based on the GHz given?
I was told that i5 would be faster than i3, but it wasn't explained in detailed.
Each of the core of i5 has a maximum of 1.3 GHz while each of the core of i3 has a speed of 1.8 GHz.
If they can't represent the precise speed, what are they for?

Comment: CPU performance depends on more than just the clock speed. Different architectures can perform different functions better.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/478150/curios-what-makes-cpus-better-than-others, http://superuser.com/questions/543702/why-are-newer-generations-of-processors-faster-at-the-same-clock-speed, http://superuser.com/questions/616829/why-have-cpu-manufacturers-stopped-increasing-the-clock-speeds-of-their-processo?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can't judge the processing speed based on the clock speed. The clock speed just tells you how fast the clock runs. Its correlation to instructions per second (which is what you really care about) depends on many, many other factors.